# Convert small letter to capital letter

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert string in small letter to capital letter.
I got some error (access volation)
what whould do?

```
int main()
{
    char str[10];
    int i=0;
    scanf("%s", &str);
    while (str[i] !=0)
    {
        str[i] += -32;
        printf("%s", str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

thx

Comment: If it's homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Apart from your bug, you're not incrementing i --> infinite loop

Comment: There are no guarantees that all letters are in sequence on all systems. Where I live, we believe that åäö are valid letters.

Comment: I like `+= -32` !! I'd write as `-= 32` :)

Answer (score 5):

1. If you enter a string longer than 9 characters, `scanf()` will try to write past the end of your string buffer.
2. Your while-loop never terminates as you never change `i`.
3. You should use `"%c"` as format string in your `printf()` call, since you are wrting characters, not null-terminated strings.

Comment: I dont get it, I'm entered string less than 9 and it still dont work

Comment: @yEL155: I listed several mistakes in your code.  You fixed the first one and it still does not work.  Perhaps consider to fix the remaining ones as well...

Comment: `scanf("%s", &str);` is not correct anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    char str[10];
    int i=0;
    scanf("%s", str);
    while (str[i] != 0)
    {
        str[i] += -32;
            i++;
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

and of course, you must check overflow of str...

Answer (score 2):

As cprogrammer said

> You better use toupper
>
> ```
> /* toupper example */
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <ctype.h>
> int main ()
> {
>   int i=0;
>   char str[]="Test String.\n";
>   char c;
>   while (str[i])
>   {
>     c=str[i];
>     putchar (toupper(c));
>     i++;
>   }
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

But if not, and you want to do it your way

```
int main()
{
    char str[10];
    int i=0;
    scanf("%s", &str);
    while (str[i]!='\0' && i<10)  
    {// You forgot this: '\0' instead of 0 and also i<10
        str[i] += -32;
        printf("%c", str[i]);//char, not string
        i++; //And this
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes here:

1. `scanf("%s", &str);` - since str is a pointer to char, you don't need to give its address, but `scanf("%s", str);`. (and as sven said, it's unsafe)
2. `while (str[i] !=0)` this is an endless loop, you should increment `i` at the end of the while block.
3. `str[i] += -32;` will modify any char you're at, you should check if this is a lower case any time, for example:

   if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'){ 
            str[i] -=32;
       } //couldn't format this line for some reason....
4. `printf("%s", str[i])` is again wrong way to use printf,  since `%s` expects to `char*`, and `str[i]` is a `char`. instead, use `printf("%c", str[i])` which expects a char

Answer (score 0):

You better use [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/toupper/)

```
/* toupper example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main ()
{
  int i=0;
  char str[]="Test String.\n";
  char c;
  while (str[i])
  {
    c=str[i];
    putchar (toupper(c));
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main();
{
    int i, count;
    char str[200];
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a string");
    scanf("%s", str);
    count = strlen(str);
    for(i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        if((str[i] >= 97) && (str[i] <= 122))
        {
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: please try to avoid answers with code only, add some explanation to your code for a higher quality answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) ( `&` ) operator technique to make small letter to capital letter.

```
char ch = letter & 223; [letter = a-z] // Now ch is all time capital letter
```

Comment: Awesome technique.